# How to prepend a specific string to a select option in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple html form with a dropdown list with the name of images which I will be saving the selecting into the database:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
    <table width="450px">
        <select name="rating">
            <option value="image1">image1</option>
            <option value="image2">image2</option>
            <option value="image3">image3</option>
            <option value="image4">image4</option>
        </select>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What I want to do is to save the whole path of the image without showing the path to the user, so I would like to do is to append a static path to any of the selections of the user when they press submit e.g. prepend: “path/to/my/file” to the selected image so if they select image1 it would save path/to/my/file/image1.png into my database.

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: If you don't want the user to see it, you can't send it to their browser at all. Why not append the value on the server after submitting?

Comment: Where is the path located based on your example?  Could you put the path in the value attribute?

Comment: As the others said: If you don't want the user to see it you should not do it in JavaScript/HTML, so you'll need to tell us what kind of server framework you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by setting the path in the `value` attribute of each `<option>`. Either you do it server side or you can do it in **jQuery**:

```
$('[name="rating"] > option').each(function() {
    this.value = '/path/to/file/' + this.value;
})
```